# google script : how can we extract hyperlink of label using script, which wont see its URL on your Google Sheets formula bar?

Tags: google-apps-script

how can we extract hyperlink of label using script, which wont see its URL on your Google Sheets formula bar ?

[image]

Comment: @TheMaster Tanaike is inevitably correct. OP, Check out the answer in the link.

Comment: Yeah.. got it.. Thank you so much..